# Problema ao efetuar uma pesquisa com data usando o Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo um código que vou fazer um query e comparando com um campo `timestamp` no `Oracle`.

A coluna do banco foi definida como `timestamp`.
O dado vem de uma requisição rest e é convertido para `LocalDateTime` do Java, adicionando horas, minutos e segundos.

O problema que ao efetuar a query não retorna em uma determinada condição.

A query é assim:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN cc.IN_CALC_SMUL = 'S' THEN 'Simulação'
        ELSE 'Oficial'
    END AS isSimulacao,
    cc.DS_CALC AS descricao,
    ccr.VL_RSULT AS valor,
    TO_CHAR(cc.DT_CRIA, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS dataCriacao,
    TO_CHAR(cc.DT_BASE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATABASE,
    cc.ID_USU_CRIA AS usuarioCriacao,
    CASE
        WHEN cc.IN_CALC_VIGNT = 'S' THEN 'Sim'
        ELSE 'Não'
    END AS isCalculoOficialVigente
FROM
    CD_CALC cc
INNER JOIN CD_CALC_RSULT ccr ON
    ccr.ID_CALC = cc.ID_CALC
    AND ccr.ID_SG_RSULT = 'RWAOPAD'
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND cc.DT_CRIA <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-10-30 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    ORDER BY cc.DT_CRIA DESC OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Segue um print dos dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o print do método que pega a String e convert para LocalDateTime

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o DDL da tabela

```
CREATE TABLE EXEMPLO.CD_CALC (
    ID_CALC NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    DT_CRIA TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CP_CD_CALC ON EXEMPLO.CD_CALC (ID_CALC);
```

Comment: Publique também a estrutura da tabela e a "perna" java do código. O que seria exatamente "não retorna em uma determinada condição"  ?

Comment: @Motta porque quando se tem no where a condição que atende e existe no banco o registro deveria retornar, adicionei na pergunta o print da conversão da String para LocalDateTime e o DDL, removi parte desnecessarias